# Impact multiple same elements & avoid null errors when not in DOM, plain JavaScript vs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have several date `inputs`, which I'd like to change `color` after user input. With jQuery I could do:

```js
$('input[type="date"]').on('change', function() {
  var el = $(this).val();
  if (el === '') {
    $(this).css('color', '#9c9c9c');
  } else {
    $(this).css('color', '#000000');
  }
})
```

```css
input[type="date"] {
  color: #9c9c9c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
<input type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

But, when I try to achieve the same with plain JS (`document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll().forEach()`), I'm unable to. I can only make the first input work with the `document.querySelector()` approach:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
el ? el.onchange = function() {
  if (this.value === '') {
    this.style.color = '#9c9c9c';
  } else {
    this.style.color = '#000000';
  }
} : "";

//tried also
/*document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]').forEach(function() {
   this.onchange = function() {
    if (this.value === '') {
      this.style.color = '#9c9c9c';
    } else {
      this.style.color = '#000000';
    }
  }
});*/
```

```css
input[type="date"] {
  color: #9c9c9c;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
<input type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

Based on [this excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267161/decument-queryselector-on-elements-not-in-dom), I'm also using a ternary operator to check if the element exists in the DOM first, otherwise I'm getting error on pages where the inputs are not in the DOM.

**How to achieve this with plain JS & avoiding null errors on non-existent DOM elements?**

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[type="date"]')` gives you the first Element of that kind. You would have to use `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]')` and loop over the Array it returns. Vanilla JS is not jQuery.

Comment: @PHPglue Not quite.  `querySelectorAll` returns an array-like object (a `NodeList`), not an actual `Array` (so even in this case, `forEach` would not work)

Comment: Do `var ary = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]'))` then.

Comment: Considering both `for` & `forEach` solutions work, any performance reason why to use one over the other? Tested here https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/a16aru5m/46/ Also same question with `.onchange` vs `addEventListener`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you using `document.querySelectorAll`, it always return an array. use `forEach` for loop all item in array (array can be empty but it is empty array). You can using `addEventListener` for listening event onchange, and this is example:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]');
inputs.forEach (function (item) {
  item.addEventListener('change', function () {
    this.classList.add("red");
  })
})
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
<input type="date">
<input type="date">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is how you are looping the elements of the query:

Works fine with a simple `for`

Or change to call it like this:

```
[].forEach.call(listElements, function(element) {
    //Add event onchange
});
```

*I changed the color to red to a better visualization*

```js
var listElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]');

[].forEach.call(listElements, function(element) {
  
});


for (var i in listElements) {
    element = listElements[i];
    element.onchange = function() {
        if (this.value === '') {
            this.style.color = 'red';
        } else {
            this.style.color = '#000000';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
input[type="date"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
<input type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
<input type="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

Comment: Heh.  Some people might say that a red on blue color scheme does not qualify as "better"

Comment: @Tibrogargan Sure! But to me red is much clearer to see than just changing black color to gray, but that is just my _personal taste_

Answer (score 1):

at `this.onchange = function()`
`this` would be `window`, not each element

so simply replace `this` like :

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]').forEach(function(element) {
   element.onchange = function() {
      if (element.value === '') {
          element.style.color = '#9c9c9c';
      } else {
          element.style.color = '#000000';
      }
  }
});
```

You can learn more from this post : [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)